# Pass binary data from QML to C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a 'binary string' in JavaScript inside of QML, representing raw bytes that I want to pass to C++ (to send over an established socket).

I was using code like this:

```js
// QML
onSomeSignal: {
  var proto = new MyMessage();  // https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js
  var bbuf  = proto.encode();   // https://github.com/dcodeIO/bytebuffer.js
  var bytes = bbuf.toBinary();
  messageBridge.send(bytes);
}
```

```c++
// C++
void MessageBridge::send(const QString& data) {
    if(m_tcpSocket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState) {
        m_tcpSocket->write(encodeVarint32(data.length()).toLocal8Bit());
        m_tcpSocket->write(data.toLocal8Bit());
    }
}
```

However, I discovered that translating the JavaScript string to a QString was sometimes changing the bytes (presumably because of encodings).

The following code works, but it's inefficient, converting the byte buffer to a binary string, then a JS array, converting to a QVariantList and then piecemeal populating a QByteArray.

```js
// QML
onSomeSignal: {
  var bytes = (new MyMessage()).encode().toBinary();
  var bytea = [];
  for (var i=bytes.length;i--;) bytea[i] = bytes.charCodeAt(i);
  messageBridge.send(bytes);
}
```

```c++
// C++
void MessageBridge::send(const QVariantList& data) {
    if(m_tcpSocket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState) {
        m_tcpSocket->write(encodeVarint32(data.length()).toLocal8Bit());
        m_tcpSocket->write(data.toLocal8Bit());
        QByteArray bytes(data.length(),'\0');
        for (int i=0; i<data.length(); i++) bytes[i] = data[i].toInt();
        m_tcpSocket->write(bytes);
    }
}
```

What is an efficient way to pass either a [`ByteBuffer`](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bytebuffer.js) or binary string from QML/JavaScript to Qt/C++, in a way that gives me something I can [write to a `QTcpSocket`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write)?

Comment: For my project use I ended up implementing a `Data` qml wrapper around a `QDataStream` using a `QBuffer` as a device, backed by a `QByteArray, implemented read and write for the basic types - bool, int, real, string, other `Data`. So if protobuf is not a necessity, you can just do and use that, is is simple enough and it works out of the box with Qt apis.

Comment: @ddriver Thanks for sharing. In my case I am sending protobuf from QML as generated and encoded by protobufjs, so the (custom) ByteArray class must be the starting point for my data.

Comment: You could try to and from base 64 encoding string.

Comment: Have you tried using QByteArray as the function argument? That shouldn't incur any encoding.

But I guess the main question is if the message preparation and encoding really needs to be done in the GUI instead of in the application core

Comment: Well, js libraries are technically not gui. The same goes for qml - it is just markup, you can use it for a lot more than gui. On the topic - it is high time Qt implements default conversion for JS uint8array <-> QByteArray as it has for most other important types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// QML
onSomeSignal: {
    var bytes = new MyMessage();
    messageBridge.send(bytes.toArrayBuffer());
}
```

and the array buffer will nicely fit into a QByteArray:

```
// C++
void MessageBridge::send(const QByteBuffer& data) {
    if (m_tcpSocket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState) {
        m_tcpSocket->write(encodeVarint32(data.size()).toLocal8Bit());
        m_tcpSocket->write(data);
}
```

Now please tell me how to go the other way from a QByteBuffer in C++ to a useful protobuf.js object in a QML signal  :)

Comment: Now @dirtyfreebooter just has to show us how to do it the other way in Qt5.8.

Answer (score 2):

Qt 5.7 does not understand QByteArray from C++ to QML, so it just wraps it into an opaque QVariant, making it useless in QML, except for passing it back into C++ at a later time.

Qt 5.8+ adds support for QByteArray type. When passed from C++ to QML, either as a return variable or a signal parameter, the QByteArray is converted to an ArrayBuffer. This is useful for protobufs, as the protobuf's javascript API can directly decode an ArrayBuffer type.

Comment: Using 5.9.2 here, returning a byte array from C++ to QML results in an empty opaque object that has no properties whatsoever, nothing visible or usable from JS.