# QByteArray to Javascript Buffer or serializable type in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qtwebengine

I have registered a class that returns the result of reading a file this is of the type `QByteArray`, that seems not to be a natively supported file in `QML`, so I get some gibberish, even if its the correct data I cannot convert it to a blob.

So i am trying to get at the end a Javascript type of `File` or `Blob` that itself is the end goal. So this 2 javascript types do not exist in QML.

My question is how can I create a bufferish type that go through a serialized Json object to my embedded web.

PS. even being a bad idea i have even try QString but i have lost data in the conversion of `QByteArray` to `QString`

Answer (score 3):

It's `ArrayBuffer` since Qt 5.8.

**2016-03-05** 3b7e2a69f7eb8597c807de39b4de39721e9e2bd2

Convert QByteArray in C++ type to ArrayBuffer in QML and vice-versa

Nobuaki Sukegawa, Reviewed-by: Simon Hausmann.

[SO mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41367921/4742108)

[Qt tracker somewhat related mentions](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55562?focusedCommentId=329662&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-329662)

Comment: ok thanks for your response, now i understand a bit better the mapping in QML :). I might have not written correctly the title, and because there is a 2 step thing going around is a bit confusing so I have ReadFile(C++, QByteArray) -> wrapper of web (QML, ArrayBuffer) -> web (js, ???), i am using qtwebchannel so is a signal that sends a json object, and in this case the data is always empty due no conversion then due ArrayBuffer and json

Comment: Note that (as of 2017-Nov-7) `QByteArray` ↔ `ArrayBuffer` is [currently undocumented](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62595).

Answer (score 1):

What I did for my needs was to wrap a combination of `QByteArray`, `QBuffer` and `QDataStream` in a `QObject` together with functions to read and write primitive types and save to / load from disk and some other auxiliary functionality, to create what turned out to be a very useful `BinaryData` type which as a `QObject` derived , can be freely passed around, without any potentially costly conversions taking place.

This allows to use it in an identical way in both C++ and QML, if needed you can easily make a `toArrayBuffer()` method for it.

Comment: thanks a lot @ddriver sounds like a good option so i am taking note of it :). it does not finish solving my issue as non of them are serializable to be sent to my embedded web. but in any case i have decided to use websocket to send that data so both of your answers are valid :).

Comment: Curious what is your definition of "serializable "?

Comment: in this case i agree is not probably the best word. i should say serializable to a javascript object that can be passed throught a qwebchannel, setting an ArrayBuffer to a property of a js object in qml causes it to be empty, hence there is a casting problem when assign as part of a json.

Comment: You could convert it to a plain array in an overloaded `YourType.prototype.toJson`.

Comment: yes i agree, but finally for performance i think is a better solution to send the ArrayBuffer through a web socket (allows binary data) i can stream my file through it, than have an extra step to serialize the full file into an array, and pass it through the webchannel.